# What are the differences between JEE, J2EE, JSE, JME and JDK?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-me, difference

I do not understand the differences between JEE, J2EE, JSE, JME and JDK. For what I do need this stuff? May someone help me?
I found this shortcuts while learning about Java. I am new to programming.

Comment: `JSE` the basic, `J2EE` and `JEE` are the same thing just the version is different both for web app, `JME` for mobile

Comment: (simply put) you can run a complete, standalone program using Java SE (Java Standard). With Java Enterprise you don't write a *standalone* program, but you write standardized components to be run inside a (much bigger) application server. Many important "parts" of Java EE, eg. servlet and JMS, can also used by "normal" JSE programs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JEE, J2EE, JSE, JME... - it is Java libraries for different goals.

JDK it is a *Java Developer Kit* or *Software Developer Kit*. It includes a compiler, JRE and **basic** libraries for simple Java applications. **JEE, J2EE, JSE** are not simply libraries, they are grand frameworks that give more possibility for developing. You may not use them, but in this case, in a large project you will need to "reinvent the bike again". All they used JDK. So you cannot develop (execute java code) without JDK. Сompletely